# Best way to find list items whose date is in another date list in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a list of dates:

```
List<DateTime> dates;
```

And I need those date values ​​to be the ones in the following list that I am going to get ("x.Date" value).

```
var response = myObject
               .Where(x => xUserId == userId
               && Date = x.Date == //this must be the dates values 
               .Select(x => new
               {
                   x.Id,
                   x.Quantity,
                   x.Date
               })
               .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Where` ... [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-7.0):

```
var response = myObject
    .Where(x => xUserId == userId && dates.Contains(x.Date))
    ...
```